# How and where are templates in item-view.xsl called?

Tags: dspace

In the Mirage theme's `page-structure.xsl`, I see that the template with `match="dri:body"` will call  `</apply-templates>` in its `<xsl:otherwise>` case.

How does this eventually lead to the templates in `item-view.xsl` being called/generated? Most of the templates in `item-view.xsl` match elements in the `dim:` namespace (i.e. `match="dim:..."`), which are from the `mets.xml`, not the DRI xml.

I don't see any templates in any .xsl files matching the `dri` namespace (i.e. `match="dri:..."`) which explicitly call templates within `item-view.xsl`, such as the template matching `dim:dim` or `mets:file`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the DRI of an item page:
http://demo.dspace.org/xmlui/DRI/handle/10673/5

You'll find that the references to the `mets.xml` are made within the `referenceSet` elements:

```
<referenceSet id="aspect.artifactbrowser.ItemViewer.referenceSet.collection-viewer" n="collection-viewer" type="summaryView">
    <reference repositoryID="10673" type="DSpace Item" url="/metadata/handle/10673/5/mets.xml">
        <referenceSet rend="hierarchy" type="detailList">
            <head>This item appears in the following Collection(s)</head>
            <reference repositoryID="10673" type="DSpace Collection" url="/metadata/handle/10673/2/mets.xml"/>
        </referenceSet>
    </reference>
</referenceSet>
```

These referenceSets are matched by the templates in the [.../aspect/artifactbrowser/common.xsl](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml-alt/aspect/artifactbrowser/common.xsl) file.

In case the of a "summaryView", this is what happens:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document($externalMetadataURL)" mode="summaryView"/>
```

will be matched by (still in common.xsl)

```
<xsl:template match="mets:METS[mets:dmdSec/mets:mdWrap[@OTHERMDTYPE='DIM']]" mode="summaryView">
```

which in turn will call

```
<xsl:call-template name="itemSummaryView-DIM"/>
```

which is one of the top templates templates in `item-view.xsl`.

Comment: Does the `$externalMetadata` used by the `apply-templates` call within `common.xsl` build off of `$externalMetadata` variables elsewhere? In `common.xsl`, I see that the `$externalMetadata` variables are only constructed by `<xsl:text>cocoon:/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@url"/>`. They don't seem to reference call the `mets.xml` file. What are they opening/calling?

Comment: `@url` is the url attribute of the `reference` element. It's in the example: `url="/metadata/handle/10673/5/mets.xml"`

Answer (score 1):

Mirage.xsl includes

```
<xsl:import href="../dri2xhtml-alt/dri2xhtml.xsl"/>
```

- https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/Mirage/Mirage.xsl#L29

That module contains the following code

```
<xsl:import href="aspect/artifactbrowser/artifactbrowser.xsl"/>
```

- https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml-alt/dri2xhtml.xsl#L43

Within that module, a "cocoon:" call is made which opens /metadata/handle/xxx/yyy/mets.xml.  You can open this url in your browser to see the markup that is being processed.

The external call is constructed here.

```
<xsl:variable name="externalMetadataURL">
    <xsl:text>cocoon://metadata/handle/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$handle"/>
    <xsl:text>/mets.xml</xsl:text>
    <!-- Since this is a summary only grab the descriptive metadata, and the thumbnails -->
    <xsl:text>?sections=dmdSec,fileSec&amp;fileGrpTypes=THUMBNAIL</xsl:text>
    <!-- An example of requesting a specific metadata standard (MODS and QDC crosswalks only work for items)->
    <xsl:if test="@type='DSpace Item'">
        <xsl:text>&amp;dmdTypes=DC</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>-->
</xsl:variable>
```

- https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml-alt/aspect/artifactbrowser/discovery.xsl#L65-L75

Comment: Did you mean `discovery.xsl` instead of `artifactbrowser.xsl`?

Comment: It depends on the context.  Any point in the xslt code that makes use of $externalMetadataURL might trigger the processing of the mets.xml file content.

Comment: You are correct. That reference is in discovery.xsl.  Sorry for the confusion.  If you scan all of the xsl files, there are other examples of the cocoon: call.

Comment: Ah, no problem. Though I just deleted my comment because I figured, since artifactbrowser.xsl imports discovery.xsl, in a way `artifactbrowser.xsl` is making the external call anyway.

Comment: Should this external call be able to stand alone as is, or does it depend on anything else within `dri2xhtml` to work? For example, if I place the code above within `item-view.xsl` or `navigation.xsl` within the Mirage template, should it still be able to open `mets.xml`?

Comment: The mets.xml file will only exist for an item.  If you place the logic in a part of the stylesheet that handles collections/communities/admin pages, it might throw an error.  I am speculating here.  I have not tested this.